# Convert elements of an array to an expression and assign it to a variable

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array which contains elements that are boolean values (`True`
, `False`) and strings which represent logical operators (`'and'`, `'or'`, `'not'`).

For example:

```
array = [True, 'and', False]
```

I'd like to take the elements of this array in order and turn them into an actual expression I can assign a variable to. Meaning the following:

```
expression = True and False
```

So that I can then print the boolean result of said expression

```
print("The result of the expression is = ", expression)
```

Which should return

```
The result of the expression is = False
```

How could I achieve this? My vague idea is to iterate through the array, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to turn a string (`'and'`) to an operator (`and`).

TIA.

Comment: Are all the arrays three elements or some are longer?

Comment: Use an `if` statement. `if array[1] == 'and':`...

Comment: Remember that `not` is unary, rather than binary. Presumably `[True, 'and', 'not', True]` yields `False`.

Comment: How are you going to handle multiple `'not'` tokens in a row? E.g. `[True, 'and', 'not', 'not', True]`

Comment: They can be longer than three elements, as the contents of the array are based on user input. Essentially, it's a boolean expression.
For example, `p ^ q ^ ~q`
Which can turn into `p and q and not q`
Assuming `p` is assigned a value of `True` and q has a value of `False`
The array would then be `[True, 'and', False, 'and', 'not', False]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
array = [True, 'and', False]
expression = eval(' '.join([str(i) for i in array]))
print("The result of the expression is = ", expression)
```

Output:

```
The result of the expression is =  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple 3-step iterative algorithm to solve this without relying on `eval`, and assuming `and` has higher operator precedence than `or`. If there is no operator precedence, you could combine steps 2 and 3 into a single iteration.

1. First, iterate through the array, getting rid of all `not`. For instance, convert all `not True` to `False` and vice versa. Now we are left with only `and`, `True`, `or`, and `False`.
2. Then, iterate through the array evaluating all `and` expressions.
3. Finally, return `True` if there are any `True` left in the array, otherwise return `False`.

Here's an implementation. It's not the most efficient, since [deleting in the middle of a list takes O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), but it shows how the algorithm works:

```
from copy import copy

def remove_nots(lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        # if we encounter a `not`, remove it, and negate the following element
        if lst[i] == 'not':
            del lst[i]
            # to negate a `not`, we remove it
            if lst[i] == 'not':
                del lst[i]
            # otherwise, it must be a boolean, so we can use native not
            else:
                lst[i] = not lst[i]
        else:
            i += 1

def resolve_and(lst):
    i = 0
    while i + 2 < len(lst):
        # if we encounter an `and` expression, replace it with the result
        if lst[i + 1] == 'and':
            result = lst[i] and lst[i + 2]
            del lst[i+2]
            del lst[i+1]
            lst[i] = result
        else:
            i += 1
    

def resolve(lst):
    # create a copy to work on, since we'll be modifying the list
    lst_copy = copy(lst)
    remove_nots(lst_copy)
    resolve_and(lst_copy)
    return True in lst_copy

print(resolve(lst = [False, 'or', True, 'and', 'not', 'not', 'not', False])) # True
```

Comment: You may wish to keep a count of _consecutive_ `'not'` tokens as you iterate through. An even number of consecutive `'not'`s can be ignored. An odd number would be treated the same as one.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I just added an example implementation and made sure to account for that. Instead of counting, I allowed `not` to be a valid operand of `not`, the result of which is that both `not`s go away.